# unable to read otml file

Tags: decryption

I'm trying to open a game file (.otml) that seems to be encrypted. When opening one of the files with notepad++ I get the following text

ENC3ž4®£i{Ñ7  :  £i{Ñš²É ‚NR“ÿUªˆ¿+ó6ug¾°¦.ë´7º™ïÐvä@6ÿ¾>ZEò
—[\HÌ†‡sYëÕõ¶Ë—ÛE:O`Ú&w‰$Èé)àìPm“¤oþ×ÒåèPáA#h‡Ñ-UÂšF|b"Á†*3{7£(¢¦eÃdÆ)'÷vê6-ÔéÚÞ¦îô‘46þx1úLÊ%7!§ÜÿFJ¸¤]ÕÔYã©#329 ZŸ¿ÓQc’‘E”ÿ‡HÅ/XHÝ
?#ìåÛé7â5âÂË´†5[§F¥à <Q±¡äi$Z*M÷sÑ‡ Ô¸´ä{sïH’E•\…²¿"Š>¶î   ¾Àgûýã&ÊßfÆšH3˜1Ø\øäë÷NGÏSöæ}{i£

I have tried to search for the encryption key with idapro but i couldnt figure it out,

anyone could point me to a better direction?

Comment: At first glance it looks like it could just be a simple XOR cipher. What game is it from? Any more info?

Comment: game is called Ravendawn. Since you mentioned XOR ive tried to bruteforce it but still no sucess.. all the game files have the same kind of characters, and they all start with the exact same words "ENC3"..